# Apache PIG - Convert millseconds into TimeStamp Unix

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, converters

I've the following field: `1388481000000` as the number of milliseconds elapsed from the Unix Epoch (1970-01-01 UTC)

How can I convert to Unix TimeStamp? 
I'm trying to use:

```
ToUnixTime(1388481000000,'dd/MM/yyyyHH:mm:ss','GMT')
```

but it gives me error...

How can I convert into Unix Timestamp? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing things up.[ToUnixTime](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#to-unix-time) syntax is ToUnixTime(datetime) where the parameter is a datetime object.What you have is the milliseconds elapsed from the Unix epoch (1970-01-01 UTC).I assume you are trying to convert the milliseconds to a datetime object for which you will have to use [ToDate](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#to-date) and the syntax is ToDate(milliseconds).

```
ToDate(1388481000000)
```

Comment: I've defined my field as chararray... What type do you recommend to make the transformation?

Comment: use long to load the milliseconds.You can still use chararray but will have cast like this ToDate((long)1388481000000) See here for datatypes https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#Data+Types